# If I miss the train, can I use the reservation ticket in general compartment of next train in India?

Tags: trains, tickets, bookings, indian-railways

Indian railways.

I have a reserved second seating (2S). 
can I use this 2S reserved ticket to travel in the general compartment of the next/previous trains.

Comment: Which country company and ticket type?